# The asynchronous connection pool implementation in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, connection, pool, rust-tokio

I have a Tokio TCP back-end application, which, briefly, after receiving a request, reads something from Redis, writes something to PostgreSQL, uploads something via HTTP, sends something to RabbitMQ etc. Processing each request takes a lot of time, so a separate task for each request is created. As sharing connections is impossible in asynchronous models, some connection pooling is required. For now, new connections are established on each request, and it is extremely excessive.

I have been looking for an asynchronous connection pool implementation in Rust, but have not found any of them up to date.

I would like to hear some advice on how to implement it myself.

The only idea I have come up with is:

1. Implement a `Stream/Sink` object with an inner collection of connections. It does not matter whether it is LIFO or FIFO, since the connections are identical. On the application startup, N connections are allocated.
2. Now I am not sure if it is possible to share such a pool among tasks, but if it were possible, tasks would poll the stream for a connection instance (instead of establishing their own one), use it, and then put back.
3. If there were no connections available, the stream might establish more of them or ask the task to hang on (depending on its configuration).
4. If a connection fails, it gets dropped and the pool now contains N-1 connections, so it may decide to allocate a new one on the next request.

So I have two problems I cannot find proper answers anywhere:

1. Must/can/should I share the stream/sink-pool among tasks in some way? Anyway, I see some `Shared` futures in the `futures` crate.
2. There are some gloomy points in the tokio/futures tutorial. E.g. it does not explain how do I notify the uppermost task, that is, how do I implement the mythical innermost future, which does not pool anything itself, but still has to notify the upper futures.

Or is my approach completely wrong? I could start playing with it by myself, but I have a strong suspicion that I have missed something, e.g. a one-click solution.

Comment: Since this question in its current form appears off-topic, you may wish to look at other resources. More open-ended questions and discussions are welcome on [the Rust-Beginners IRC channel](https://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust-beginners), [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), or [the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/). There is also a list of Rust IRC channels on [the community page](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/community.html#irc-channels).

Comment: For what it's worth, there is [bb8](https://github.com/khuey/bb8), which looks like an async version of r2d2, but it doesn't really seem to have docoumentation.

Comment: It also seems a bit outdated, as it still uses tokio_core etc.

Comment: I have implemented a simple pool that stores asynchronous connection objects in a `VecDeque`. There is no supervisor that keeps connections alive. So, if an acquired connection is dead, it is being renewed, used and put back in the queue. If all the connections are busy, some extra connections are allocated and then discarded (logging some warnings). So, it is a lazy-initialization pool without any inner threads. If there is a lot of traffic, connections will be used frequently enough to keep them alive.

Comment: It seems that [bb8](https://github.com/khuey/bb8) has been updated recently (and does have an adapter for redis). It's working well for me with current tokio.